# Sending coap messages via nativescript-js application

Tags: nativescript, coap

I want to send coap messages using an application developed on nativescript framework. Are there any available modules in nativescript or how to use node-coap for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any plugin as of today that supports CoAP. You might want to write one.

A quick search shows there are native clients available on respective platforms, [iCoAP](https://github.com/stuffrabbit/iCoAP) / [spitfirefox](https://github.com/okleine/spitfirefox) for which you could write a plugin or directly use the apis in your project.

Read more about accessing native or third party libraries in [iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries) / [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/accessing-packages) from the docs.